# %c formatted string shows different behaviour in the shell and in C

Tags: shell-script, c, printing, printf, ascii

If i write a very simple line of code in C:

```
printf("Ascii char for %d is %c\n",65,65);
```

It simply prints `A`, as ascii value of 65 corresponds to character `A`. But if I use the same code in shell and write the command

```
printf "Ascii char for %d is %c\n" 65 65
```

it shows the output as `Ascii char for 65 is 6`. I was expecting the same output as in the C language and logically also it should print the character corresponding to the given ascii code.

Why is it showing different behaviour in these cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%c` takes a string and prints the first character of that string.  If the string is `65`, as in your example, then it would print `6`.

This is specified by [the POSIX specification for the `printf` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/printf.html):

> The argument to the `c` conversion specifier can be a string containing zero or more bytes. If it contains one or more bytes, **the first byte shall be written** and any additional bytes shall be ignored. If the argument is an empty string, it is unspecified whether nothing is written or a null byte is written.
>
> **The argument operands shall be treated as strings** if the corresponding conversion specifier is `b`, `c`, or `s` [...]

This means that *the argument* of the `%c` format is interpreted different in C (where a small positive integer will be converted to a `char`) and in the shell (where the same integer remains a string containing several digit characters).  The format itself does the same thing though; it outputs a single byte as a character.

However:

```
$ printf '%d %b\n' 65 '\0101'
65 A
```

101 is 65 in octal. And `%b` is specified in POSIX as

> An additional conversion specifier character, `b`, shall be supported as follows. The argument shall be taken to be a string that can contain `<backslash>`-escape sequences. [...]
>
> `\0ddd`, where `ddd` is a zero, one, two, or three-digit octal number that shall be converted to a byte with the numeric value specified by the octal number.

It's an *additional* conversion specifier, since it's not available in standard C. It is however needed in the shell as we don't have typed variables (in the POSIX shell).

Also:

```
$ printf '%d %b\n' 65 "$( printf '\\0%o\n' 65 )"
65 A
```

Here we first convert 65 to an octal number in the `\0ddd` format using `%o`, before using the result of that in another `printf` that uses `%b`.

Comment: so it means `%c` does shows a different behaviour in LINUX as compared to C ?right ?

Comment: @Noshiii I would say that it behaves _slightly_ differently in C than in the shell, yes.  The argument that you pass in the shell is _always_ a string, while in C it's a typed integer. The actual output is similar is nature though: A single character is outputted.  It's not the same character because of how the argument is processed.

Comment: @Noshiii I've added more explanation regarding this to the answer.

Comment: `%c` in C takes an `int` and converts that to `unsigned char` according to the book HARBISON, Samuel P. C: a reference manual. Prentice Hall, 2002.

Comment: @thrig I have slightly amended my choice words in the sentence that I _think_ you are referring to.